# Editing a WP theme to include a slider in HERO column

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, editing

I am building a page (before my developer can get to it).  I would like to put a rev slider in the hero position, yet I do not know what "page" to edit in the editor, NOR, do I know the code.  If I wanted to include a slider in a "free" theme, what page would I edit and what code would I use.

I do have a custom css plugin installed.  Here is the [site](http://deniselawrence.planetconcourse.com) if needed for reply.  I appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: Well you just need to copy the revolution slider shortcode and paste it into the page where you want to show the  , your slider will show there

Comment: Well...it is a theme that is already made.  It has a customizer and no place to put the shortcode.